# Rails share code between migrations (aka concerns)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, migration, helper, raise

I have a few migrations within identical helpers

```
  private

  def add_earthdistance_index table_name, options = {}
    execute "CREATE INDEX %s_earthdistance_ix ON %s USING gist (ll_to_earth(%s, %s));" %
      [table_name, table_name, 'latitude', 'longitude']
  end

  def remove_earthdistance_index table_name
    execute "DROP INDEX %s_earthdistance_ix;" % [table_name]
  end
```

And I'm trying to avoid copy-paste them every time. Is there any way to share code between migrations without monkey-patching the base class? I want to find something like `concerns` for models.

Answer (score 8):

**Solution**

Add `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/db/migrate/concerns/**/"]` to `config/application.rb`

Create `db/migrate/concerns/earthdistanceable.rb` file within

```
module Earthdistanceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def add_earthdistance_index table_name, options = {}
    execute "CREATE INDEX %s_earthdistance_ix ON %s USING gist (ll_to_earth(%s, %s));" %
      [table_name, table_name, 'latitude', 'longitude']
  end

  def remove_earthdistance_index table_name
    execute "DROP INDEX %s_earthdistance_ix;" % [table_name]
  end

end
```

Use it:

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  include Earthdistanceable

  def up
    ...
    add_earthdistance_index :requests
  end

  def down
    remove_earthdistance_index :requests

    drop_table :requests
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you could do something like:

```
# lib/helper.rb
module Helper
  def always_used_on_migrations
    'this helps' 
  end
end
```

## Migration

```
include Helper
class DoStuff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    p always_used_on_migrations
  end

  def self.down
    p always_used_on_migrations
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice. But too explicit for me. I'd like to find something like `concerns` for models.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry if it didn't suit you.

Comment: @Arsen: do you _know_ how concerns work? It's just a module that you include in a class. And a migration is just a class. It's the same thing as with models, literally.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I know now. Because I have just implemented it.